# Check for loaded pages in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this piece of code in my background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"alert('Loaded');"});
    }
});
```

This should give me an alert every time a page is loaded, but it doesn't..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `tabs` permission on your manifest file. Also use the tabId on `executeScript`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code:"alert('Loaded');"});
    }
});
```

If this doesn't resolve your problem give me more details.

Comment: +1 Probably an issue with the missing `tabs` permission. When `null` is used instead of `tabId`, the alert will still show, in the current active tab. Another possible cause is a (syntax) error in the background script, which prevents the script from running. To debug a background page, visit `chrome://extensions/`, enable `Developer mode`, then click on `background.js` at your extension, to open the  developer tools (which runs in the context of the background script).

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I changed the null to the tabId. The tab permission was already set